# Render app dynamically based on the context

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I'm developing a react application that will be slighty different in different situations.

The app will be used on third party web services as plugin loaded in an iframe. In this case I must know who request the app because:

- I must rebrand (load a different css)
- Disable or enable different services.

Moreover the app will be used as our service and in this case must load the default configuration with our brand and all the services.

I'm wondering how to do that. The simplest things that came in my mind is use the localStorage and save a setting variable just before load the iFrame and in the react app I can use the localStorage to understand what to do. Is this a reliable solution?

Also, the iFrame load the website using a request, maybe I can pass a query parameter and set the style and some other values based on that.

Not sure which is the best way to do that.

Comment: query param seems pretty straightforward. can even put json in it

Answer (score 0):

You can also set cookies based on who is going to use it, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie, but make sure to have the secure flag switched on.

An example, this is client side

import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

cookies.set('requestedParty', 'Google', { path: '/' });

console.log(cookies.get('requestedParty'));

Comment: Add a description on how can he/she do that. Otherwise once if the link is revoked your answer turns useless.